# How to reuse method by passing different class object to the same method?

Tags: c#-4.0

How to reuse method by passing different class object? I have 2 different classes, ClassOne and ClassTwo, in the method ProcessMessage I want to pass the Class also, but how?
Like this in someway //ProcessMessage(classText, objectTwo);

```
class ClassOne
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassOne");
    }
}



class ClassTwo 
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassTwo");
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var objectOne = new ClassOne();
        var classText = objectOne.MethodOne();
        ProcessMessage(classText, objectOne);


        var objectTwo = new ClassTwo(); 
        classText = objectTwo.MethodOne();
        //ProcessMessage(classText, objectTwo);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void ProcessMessage(string classText, ClassOne testClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassText:{0}", classText);
    }
}
```

If I use this(after getting help from you guys), I recognise know, how can I use testClass?

Like:  var text= testClass.MethodOne(); or something

```
public static void ProcessMessage(string classText, ClassOne testClass)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ClassText:{0}", classText);
}
```

Comment: why you would do so ?

Comment: The example is little strange I see now, I removed some code to get it shorter!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want this since you are not using the `testClass` parameter in `ProcessMessage` anywhere.But you can use a generic method to pass any type of class to your method:

```
public static void ProcessMessage<T>(string classText, T testClass) 
     where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine("ClassText:{0}", classText);
}
```

Another alternative is creating a common interface or a base class for `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`.And change the method:

```
public static void ProcessMessage(string classText, CommonInterface testClass) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("ClassText:{0}", classText);
}
```

Comment: Or create an interface for both classes

Comment: Im using testclass parameters in, but in this example I removed it to make it shorter!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Generics, but Like Prerak K said, why?

```
    class ClassOne
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassOne");
    }
}



class ClassTwo
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassTwo");
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var objectOne = new ClassOne();
        var classText = objectOne.MethodOne();
        ProcessMessage(classText, objectOne);


        var objectTwo = new ClassTwo();
        classText = objectTwo.MethodOne();
        ProcessMessage(classText, objectTwo);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void ProcessMessage<T>(string classText, T testClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassText:{0}", classText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create an interface like this:

```
interface IProcessable {
    string MethodOne();
}

class ClassOne : IProcessable
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassOne");
    }
}

class ClassTwo : IProcessable
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassTwo");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IProcessable objectOne = new ClassOne();
        var classText = objectOne.MethodOne();
        ProcessMessage(classText, objectOne);

        IProcessable objectTwo = new ClassTwo(); 
        classText = objectTwo.MethodOne();
        ProcessMessage(classText, objectTwo);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void ProcessMessage(string classText,  IProcessable testClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassText:{0}", classText);
    }
}
```